# Interpolation inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a markup like this

```
<li ng-repeat="macro in macros" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="copyToChat($event); $hide()">
        {{macro}}
        </li>



var macros = 
[
"Hey {{activeUserName}} ! I'm sorry"
];
```

Here {{activeUserName}} is not interpolated. How can I resolve it

Comment: Is that your actual markup? It doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: what is `activeUserName` ?

Comment: Its a variable assigned to scope, for example $scope.activeUserName = "maddhur";

Comment: The question is around interpolation inside ng-repeat, whereas you repeat ends before the interpolation. See the end `</li>`

Comment: Interpolation in Angular are evaluated in context of scope variable. If macro is a random JavaScript snippet, it will not work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MadhurAhuja Take a look at my answer

Comment: @MadhurAhuja Is that stuff fine for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this way

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fffxenfj/)**

use a directive to compile your stuff from the string.

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <li ng-repeat="macro in macros" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="copyToChat($event); $hide()">
        <span compile="macro"></span>
    </li>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.macros = ["Hey {{activeUserName}} ! I'm sorry"];
    $scope.activeUserName = "maddhur";
})

app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function (scope) {
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },function (value) {
            element.html(value);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
    };
}])
```